# 'ProductList' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my `ProductList` classs, when I try to call `get_context_data` in another method, I get an error `'ProductList' object has no attribute 'object_list'`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        c = super(ProductList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c['category'] = self.category
        c['category_menu'] = self.get_category_menu()
        c['filters'] = self.filters
        c['expanded_filters'] = self.get_expanded_filters()
        c['active_filters'] = self.get_active_filters()
        c['category_list'] = self.category.get_children().filter(in_lists=True)
        c['colors_list'] = self.get_colors_list(c['object_list'])
        return c

def get_queryset(self):

    data = self.get_context_data()
```

What's causing this error?

How can I get `object_list` in my second method?

Comment: What is this code actually trying to do?

Comment: That code would not give that error, because you never refer to object_list as an attribute, only as a key; you should be seeing KeyError. Please show the real code and the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: It would in the implementation of the superclass. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for such a blurred question. It's just my first try of Django. I read some documentation and realized that I can actually get a list of objects I need with the `filter()`:

```
data = self.model.objects.filter(categories__in=self.get_category_menu())
```

Answer (score 17):

You might be getting the error on following [line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L130) in `get_context_data()` of the super class:

```
queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
```

The [`get`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L159) method of `BaseListView` sets the `object_list` on the view by calling the `get_queryset` method:

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

But, in your case, you are calling `get_context_data()` in `get_queryset` method itself and at that time `object_list` is not set on the view.