# Django Create Model from ListView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a ListView to list instances of a model and I want users to be able to create a new instance from the same page.

I tried multiple inheritance with CreateView, FormMixin and ModelFormMixin and I got all of them to work, but when a form is invalid, I don't get validation, I just get 'View' object has no attribute 'object_list'.

How can I achieve that?

Should I split my concerns and have a separate view just to handle Model creation? If so, how can I get the invalid errors back to the same template?

My code atm:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyView(CreateView, ListView):

    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'MyPage.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_page')
```

Edit: Adding traceback:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/

Django Version: 3.0.8
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tracker']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 144, in post
    return self.form_invalid(form)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 61, in form_invalid
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 67, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 100, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
  File "/Users/bidu/gitfolder/expense_tracker/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 115, in get_context_data
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list

Exception Type: AttributeError at /create/
Exception Value: 'CreateTransactionView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

Comment: Why not just have a link on the `ListView` page to the `CreateView` page?

Comment: Can you post the traceback? You will probably have to add some way of setting `object_list` on a POST request, there will be other issues like `get_context_object_name` being a common method for both classes but both return different things

Comment: @MeL I need to be able to get the form validation in the same template if It is invalid, I don't know a way of doing this if I separate the views.

Comment: @IainShelvington Added the traceback

Answer (score 0):

Lot of views that involve a form and a list of objects. Rather than trying to mixin things, just add the queryset into the context data as below. *Don't miss to remove your class `ListView`*.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'MyPage.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_page')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = self.model.objects.all()
        return super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Using this example I got the error `'MyView' object has no attribute 'object_list'`.
If I change `class MyView(CreateView, ListView):` to `class MyView(ListView, CreateView):` I got the following error on a GET request: `'MyView' object has no attribute 'object'`

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom form validation, per the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/):

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before

    def clean_recipients(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
        if "fred@example.com" not in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")
        return data
```

> 'View' object has no attribute 'object_list'

About this error that you are getting though, after doing some research, I think you need to override the default `self.object_list` variable, as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37675953). But again, I don't think you'll have to deal with this after you started to use CreateView.